# How to show that errors exhibit a quadratic convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, approximation, newton-raphson

Given the simple cubic function $$f(x) = x^3 - 1 = 0,$$
You can use the Newton Raphson method to solve and approximate one solution to the function like so:

| n | $x_n$ | Absolute Error |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.41667 | 0.41667 |
| 2 | 1.11053 | 0.11053 |
| 3 | 1.01064 | 0.01064 |
| 4 | 1.00011 | 0.00011 |
| 5 | 1.000000012 | 0.000000012 |

Given this method to solving such a function, I've been asked to show how 'these data suggest a quadratic convergence of Newton’s iteration and demonstrate this result by treating Newton’s method as a fixed-point iteration.'

This has me quite stumped. How can I show a quadratic convergence by using these figures? And how to do so using the fixed point method? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Edit: $\operatorname{error}(n+1)\approx{\operatorname{error}(n)}^2 $

Comment: @vitamind : The other way around, $e_{n+1}=ce_n^2$. One could try to establish if there is such a constant $c$, approximatively.

Comment: Have we any ideas about how we could use the fixed point iteration method to demonstrate this? Or even vaguely how it could tie in?

Comment: Section $4$ http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~swright/416/lectures/week02.pdf?

Comment: Please be more precise on what you already know. It is quite trivial to prove that the Newton method is quadratic close to a simple (regular) root. One can interpret the Newton iteration as a fixed-point iteration $x_{n+1}=N(x_n)$ and show that $N'(x_*)=0$ which also implies quadratic or better convergence. You could empirically confirm that in your series every error is a little less than the square of the previous error. Please be more precise in where your question lies.

Comment: @Moo That is a very handy resource, thank you.